# Get display coordinates of tab using chromedriver and selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking to find the co-ordinates to a specific tab in a chromedriver instance controlled by selenium.

The scenario is as follows: I have a chromedriver instance automated with selenium that contains multiple tabs. I am looking to pin specific tabs (not all of them) and in order to do that, I am using autoit to send the necessary mouse and keyboard commands to pin the actual tab. However, in order to do that, I need to know the screen/display coordinates of the tab (so I can send the mouse there).

The chromedriver has the coordinates to the actual browser, however I have been unable to find any reference to the coordinates of the tab.

Does anyone know how I could go about getting the coordinates of a specific tab?

Update: I am using c#

Comment: AutoIt has **AutoIt Window Info Tool** which could assist you in figuring the coordinates inside the window coordinates, check out https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm

Comment: Thank you. That looks very helpful. If not for this, definielty for some other things I need to achieve. The problem is that I don't know what the tabs are going to be ahead of time. I will experiment though, it might lead me to something...

Comment: Actually, just tried it. It always returns the tab details that is currently focused as the window details, no matter where I point the mouse to. Which unfortunately, doesnt help with a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

It would be a big help if you let me know what language you are coding the tests in, however this can be achieved through checking the position of your scrollbar as the AI does not have a monitor to be limited to a resolution, essentially it can see the whole of the web-page no matter what.

Below is a link to some of the usage for checking and comparing the scrolled status, even if this isn't a direct solution i'm positive it will point you in the right direction. (This is something i had to do not very long ago)

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/02/how-to-verify-scroll-present-on-browser.html

If you have any queries let me know,

All the best, Jack

Comment: Thank you. I am using c# (sorry I should have stated that). I've had a quick read read, but I am not sure how it will help me find the tab location? This help document is related to the scroller? Are you suggesting I should be looking to use javascript to find the tab position?

Comment: Hi there @Obbles I think that i understand your question a bit more now, if you follow this guide, this will show you how to print the X and Y locations of any element, just simply add the ID to the HTML, then i'd pass the data into a variable and compare it to where it should be.

https://www.maisasolutions.com/blog/How-o-get-X-Y-coordinates-of-element-in-Selenium-WebDriver

Comment: Thank you again Jack, close but not really :) The problem is that the tab, is not an element on the page, it is part of the browser and its position is not anywhere on the page. For example, on this stack overflow page, the Title of the page is "Get display coordinates...etc", and that is written on the tab with the stackoverflow favicon...I am not enitrely sure selenium knows anything about the tab only about the title element...